# Does Ubuntu Phone support encryption?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, encryption

Does anyone know if the Ubuntu phone (especially the first official release - BQ E4.5) supports full device encryption? And if it does not, then if there are any plans for it?

Answer (score 1):

The phone images do not yet support device encryption. There are plans to add it at some point, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Canonical's founder promised to "suggest it to the team" one year ago: Here is the [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1j166z/hi_im_mark_shuttleworth_founder_of_ubuntu/cba28et)